# Return instead of print key in a Python list

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, return

I'm trying to create a function where each key in a list becomes an updatable parameter for another function.

I know that I can print all the keys in a list like this:

```
x = [a , b, c, d]

    for key in x:
        print(key)
```

But when I use the return statement like:

```
for key in x:
    return key
```

It only returns a.

How can I iterate over a list and return each value every time the loop is performed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `yield` statement maybe applied to this situation.

Comment: But why? the `for` loop already ""returns"" each element in the list. What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

When you  use the `return` statement you leave the function, thus after the first loop the interpreter exits the function and returns the first index of your list.
Could you post more code?
I see no reason to put this in a function but if you need to, one option could be :

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    storeSomeWhere = myFunction(list, i)

def myFunction(list, i):
    return list[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification is ok:

```
def PrintKey(x):
    for key in x: 
       yield key
```

Answer (score 0):

For what? The `for` loop already hands you one value from the list at a time.

If you insist you can use a generator function that accepts the list and returns the next element each time it is used (until it runs out of elements, then a `StopIteration` exception is raised):

```
def gen(li):
    for element in li:
        yield element

li = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a = gen(li)
print(next(a))
# 1
print(next(a))
# 2
print(next(a))
# 3
print(next(a))
# 4
print(next(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 63, in <module>
    print(next(a))
StopIteration
```

But again, I don't see any reason to use this in your case. Simply use the value that the `for` loop hands you.